# WebSphere Liberty profile JAXBContext ClassCastException

Tags: jaxb, websphere, classcastexception, websphere-liberty

I am using the WebSphere Liberty Profile server, version  8.5.5.3. I have an ear containing multiple wars. I deploy them all exploded (ear and the war's of the modules inside it as well).

When deploying it I get the following class cast exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: 
ClassCastException: attempting to cast bundleresource://67.fwk-1166858817/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class 
to jar:file:/C:/ws/IBM/java_1.7_64/jre/lib/rt.jar!/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.
Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.
```

I figured that the problem is that my bundled `jax-api` and `jaxb-impl` jars are not loaded, so I added to the `server.xml` the `parentLast` class loading option:

```
<enterpriseApplication id="ear-app" location="C:/ws/ear/exploded/ear-app.ear" name="ear-app" >
    <classloader delegation="parentLast" commonLibraryRef="provided-jars" privateLibraryRef="shared-libs"/>
</enterpriseApplication>
```

I added my `jax-api` and `jax-impl` jars to this folder

```
<library id="shared-libs">
    <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/lib/global" include="*.jar"/>
</library>
```

However I still have the `ClassCastException`, it looks like it is still using the `parentFirst` classloading?

I found other jaxb ClassCastException threads, but not when using the Liberty profile..

Comment: Did you tried to remove those jars from your application to load only the server classes?

Comment: No I did not try that as we need the newer library versions instead of the ones provided by WebSphere.

Comment: Liberty has `jaxb-2.2`. Which one do you need? Also what features you have enabled in `server.xml`?

Comment: Okay, I thought Liberty was on older one. I will remove the parentLast  in my server.xml. I have the following features enabled:


        <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
        <feature>wasJmsServer-1.0</feature>
        <feature>wasJmsClient-1.1</feature>
        <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
        <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a typo, but in your post you have `delegation="parentFirst"` instead of **`parentLast`**.

Did you check to just change delegation for application like this:

```
<enterpriseApplication id="ear-app" location="C:/ws/ear/exploded/ear-app.ear" name="ear-app" >
    <classloader delegation="parentLast"/>
</enterpriseApplication>
```

For more details see [Overriding a provided API with an alternative version](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/twlp_classloader_alt_api.html?cp=SSAW57_8.5.5%2F1-3-11-0-3-2-5-5&lang=en)

Comment: Ow, yes that is a typo, i used parentLast

Answer (score 0):

I worked aroud the problem by not using the parentLast. Thanks for the help.